Apple TV 3 AirPlay support on newer IOS
I am looking to buy an older A1427 model of Apple TV because I really only need it for AirPlay from the iPhone and 1080p is more than enough. I have heard that people have issues with older devices like that. But I also read that this issue only happens on streaming apps, and I only need it for showing the screen, pictures/videos from the gallery and some videos from Safari. Will it still work on IOS 16-18? Or do I have to opt for the newer version? Thanks.

It would be helpful to provide examples of these issues. But is this relevant to the question, which appear to be related to iOS / TvOS versions? Either way could you clarify your question a little bit?

@AndyGriffiths I read that apps like Netflix ask you to update the apple tv firmware to a newer version (which is no longer available on old devices) to start AirPlay. As for the other people - they just vaguely say "can't connect". Not sure what that means, that's why I'm asking the question. I am hoping that there is some sheet like "this apple tv works with iOS up to 15.3" or "all IOS versions are backwards compatible with any AirPlay device"
